# Python programming produces error

Tags: python, physics

I am trying to compile the python program for the kinetic energy. But it produces me the error as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/raj/Desktop/nn.py", line 5, in <module>
    E= m*v*v
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

for the code

```
print "enter the value of mass "
m= raw_input()
print "enter the value of the velocity?"
v= raw_input()
E= m*v*v  
print  E
```

Please explain me the error.Please correct it

Comment: covert to int () i.e.)`m= int(raw_input())`

Comment: use `v= int(raw_input())`

Comment: the error still continues Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/raj/Desktop/nn.py", line 5, in <module>
    E= m*v*v
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
>>>

Comment: @natarajanphysicist try this `print "enter the value of mass "
m= int(raw_input())
print "enter the value of the velocity?"
v= int(raw_input())
E= m*v*v  
print  E`